# Cleanup logic in AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-step-functions

I have a task with LambdaA in a Step Functions state machine to handle the failures and do the clean up, like update the job status in DDB.

But the Step Functions execution itself could also fail, for example it could breach the overall timeout or crash between steps. So I need to add an error handling LambdaB to the Step Functions CloudWatch event and do the similar clean up.

Now I'm thinking if I can remove the LambdaA and simply forward to a Fail state, which should trigger the CloudWatch event and all clean up will rely on the LambdaB.

Is this a good design? Is there any best practices about the cleanup logic design for the Step Functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, it is reasonable to de-couple complex tasks into small one and combine different AWS services.

Also, you can try to use Step Function Error Handling with `Retry` attribute.

```
"Retry": [ {
   "ErrorEquals": [ "States.Timeout" ],
   "IntervalSeconds": 3,
   "MaxAttempts": 2,
   "BackoffRate": 1.5
} ]
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html

But then, you have to add into your LambdaA with a logic that if it is a `Retry`, it is going to clean up. If not, it just moves forward.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm fine with retry, but my major concern is that, we cannot catch the whole execution error within the state machine, so LambdaA is only catch error of other steps, but I still need a LambdaB to catch the error from the whole execution. Then why I don't merge them into one and only rely on LambdaB?